# Does Delphi require a runtime library?

Tags: delphi

I want to use a language that does not need any runtime library like .NET. Do Delphi 2009 or Delphi 2010 executables require any runtime library to start?

Comment: are you sure (Delphi 2009 or Delphi 2010) ?

Comment: Yes, this is for sure.

Comment: Has been so for every version of delphi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you build without using runtime packages then the executable will have the runtime library built in to it. You can therefore distribute a single executable module that will run on a plain vanilla Windows system.

For what it is worth, .net is supplied as a Windows component and you can rely on its presence, albeit sometimes a rather lower version than you would like.